# SQLException: No suitable driver found for url=jdbc:derby

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am having problems establishing a connection to a **local Apache Derby (Java DB)** database for a small game which I've been working on. The code that throws the exception looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseController {

    private static Connection conn;
    private final String url = "url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GameDB;create=true";
    private final String username = "pdc";
    private final String password = "123";

    /**
     * Connects to the database.
     */
    public void initialize() {

        try{
            //Open a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        } catch(SQLException e){
            //Handle errors
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get the following exception:

```
    Oct 08, 2015 2:27:40 PM pdc.project.Controller.DatabaseController initialize
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GameDB;create=true
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at pdc.project.Controller.DatabaseController.initialize(DatabaseController.java:30)
    at pdc.project.Controller.Main.main(Main.java:35)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pdc.project.Controller.DatabaseController.createTable(DatabaseController.java:63)
    at pdc.project.Controller.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

I have tried the following:

- Adding derbyclient.jar to libraries (and checking that it's in the classpath under Project > Properties > Libraries)
- Adding Java DB Driver to libraries (and checking that it's in the classpath under Project > Properties > Libraries)
- Using `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver")` to register the driver
- Using `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver")` to register the driver
- Adding a dummy driver

As well as combinations of the above. None of it has worked and I think my hair is starting to fall out. Can anyone provide me the answer to why it won't register the driver?

Thank you!
I'm using Netbeans and JDK 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection URL should not begin with the characters "url=". Instead of

```java
private final String url = "url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GameDB;create=true";
```

your URL should start with "jdbc:", e.g.,

```
private final String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GameDB;create=true";
```